# How do I get both published and unpublished records using entity query?

Tags: 7, entities, database

How can I get both published and unpublished records for a content type using entity field query?

As per documentation we can filter records by **status** either published or unpublished. But I need all records irrespective of node status whether is published are unpublished.

```
 <?php $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
      ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article')
      ->propertyCondition('status', 1) // only one value accepted here
      ->range(0, 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [propertyCondition](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery::propertyCondition/7) allows three arguments. You could pass in an array containing the two values and as third parameter the operator 'IN':

```
->propertyCondition('status', array(0, 1), 'IN')
```

Note: As you have been asking for nodes, and nodes AFAIK only have the status 0 or 1, you could also just omit the status property condition entirely and would get all nodes.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article')
  ->range(0, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks Mario. It works fine! I've omitted the status property condition entirely and able to get all nodes.

Comment: Be aware but for me I had to specify clearly  `->propertyCondition('status', array(0, 1), 'IN')` because I don't why but entityFiledQuery was querying only published entities

Answer (score 0):

```
// Setup query to find show nearest to recording timestamp
$query = \Drupal::database()->select('node__field_programme_broadcast', 'nfp')
    ->fields('nfp', ['entity_id', 'field_programme_broadcast_value'])
    ->condition('nfp.field_programme_broadcast_value', $timestamp, '<')
    ->condition('nfp.field_programme_broadcast_end_value', $timestamp, '>')
    ->condition('nfd.status', 1)
    ->orderBy('nfp.field_programme_broadcast_value','DESC')
    ->range(0,1);

// add join (join method doesn't return a query object, so has to be done separately)
$query->join('node_field_data', 'nfd', 'nfd.nid = entity_id');
```

I'm working in Drupal 10.

Here's my working code. Worth noting that join doesn't return the query object, so you can't include that mid way through the query.

Also, node_data_field contains the status, so i do a join on nid as the key field.